# Axios NPM not fetching data express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I have a express.js route whose code is below: -

```js
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const hbs = require("hbs");
const weather = require("./weather");

const app = express();

app.get("/weather", (req, res) => {
  if (!req.query.city) {
    return res.send({
      error: "City Not Found",
    });
  }
  res.send({
    currentTemp: weather.temp,
  });
});
```

And I also have a file to fetch data from api using axios whose code is here

```js
const axios = require("axios");

axios
  .get(
    "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=samalkha&appid=91645b79f9eac8808153c90472150f2d"
  )
  .then(function (response) {
    module.exports = {
        temp: response.data.main.temp
    }
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error Spotter");
  });
```

As I am using res.send I should get a json with currentTemp and the value of current temp should be temperature that I will get from weather.js file but I am getting a blank json array.

Comment: Did you check what is the result of `currentTemp: weather.temp` ? Is that giving you the data
Also try to include `res.json({currentTemp: weather.temp,})` and see

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

You'll get the temperature in the localhost:3000

If you want to render the data for EJS (or something) instead of  `.then((data) => res.json(data.main.temp))` use:

```
.then((data) => res.render("index", { weather: data })
```

--

```
const URL =
  "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=samalkha&appid=91645b79f9eac8808153c90472150f2d"

const express = require("express")
const axios = require("axios")
const app = express()
const PORT = 3000

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  axios
    .get(URL)
    .then((response) => response.data)
    .then((data) => res.json(data.main.temp))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

module.exports is processed when the module is being defined. when you import weather, it does not exists therefore you get no data.

try to export a function which does the request and add a callback function as argument so you can pass the request result to it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `weather.js` to the following example:

```js
const axios = require("axios");
let temperature;

async function getTemp() {
    await axios
        .get("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=samalkha&appid=91645b79f9eac8808153c90472150f2d")
        .then(function (response) {
            temperature = response.data.main.temp
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error Spotter");
        });
}
module.exports = {
    temp: getTemp
}
```

This will actually return the fetched temperature.